# Interpretation of visa denial letter

Tags: visa-refusals, france

I want to reapply for a student visa in France, but I do not understand why the first visa was denied. The rejection letter  states that « you have not submitted sufficient evidence allowing the consular authority to insure in france that purpose of study will not be abusive »  please what does this mean?
Thanks for your prompt response.[image][image]

Comment: The blunt answer: they don't believe that you're a genuine student. Please post a photo of the complete letter with personal information blanked out. With that we might be able to give a better answer.

Comment: You might also consider asking on Expatriates stack exchange, since they are better with questions involving long-stay visa.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't realise this was a wrong site for my question. Thank you Cannon Fodder for your reply. I have attached a copy of the letter as you requested

Comment: @CannonFodder Please don't people to edit more information into their question when their question is fundamentally off-topic for the site. It just wastes their time. Instead, advise them that questions about long-term travel need to go to [expatriates.se] and advise them to post the additional information there.